# Slide floated divs after hiding an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a row of 4 `divs` that are floated left. On click, the div disappears and its siblings move to the left and take up its position. However, I'm struggling with smoothing this animation since the remaining 'divs' just jump to their new position instead of sliding over

http://jsfiddle.net/G9x8V/

Is there any way to smooth out the transition, preferably without using specific values, ie: `margin-left: x pixels;`? Also, is it possible to do this with css transitions?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp
I'm going to try it on your jsfiddle now, but I would assume it's something like:@keyframes myfirst
{
0%   {margin-left: 30px;}
25%  {margin-left: 20;}
50%  {margin-left: 10;}
100% {margin-left: 0;}
} I've never messed with css animations before though, though I'm nearly sure it's possible. (It won't work in old versions of IE though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch `fadeOut()` with `hide()`

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9x8V/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide(1000);

     })
});
```

**EDIT**

One of the directions is to wrap boxes into invisible divs that will hide after the boxes fade out. Here is the updated [fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9x8V/6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="box">1</div>
</div>
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="box">2</div>
</div>
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
width: 600px;
}
.box {
width: 100%;
height: 120px;
background: red;
float: left;
}

.outer-box {
width: 20%;
height: 120px;
margin-left: 2.5%;
float: left;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').on('click', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).parents('.outer-box').hide(1000);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I originally had, but I've been trying to split it into two events; a fade out of a div, and then the sliding over of the remaining divs.

Comment: @cat-t check out the edit of the answer. let me know if this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Bojana's answer, but I'll give you another option, as I worked a little on it(it's not done, implementation isn't as easy as bojana's):

http://jsfiddle.net/G9x8V/4/

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {margin-left: 18%;}
25%  {margin-left: 12%;}
50%  {margin-left: 6%;}
100% {margin-left: 0%;}
}
```

And then you'd have to update the javascript so it occured on click, not on page load, and you might want to put in more points on that animation and switch to px.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Or do you actually want the blocks to slide along?

**CSS3 Ease**

```
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/G9x8V/2/)

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $('.box').on('click', function(){
      $(this).fadeOut(function() {
          $(this).next().animate({'left': '0px'}, 1000).next().animate({'left': '27.5%'}, 1000).next().animate({'left': '50%'}, 1000); 
      });
  })
});
```

[JSFIDDLE jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/G9x8V/9/)

Comment: I'm looking for all the blocks to slide along, so if the first div is clicked on and disappears, the remaining 3 slider to the left.

Comment: Okay I will work on this code more when I get home but I think I may be able to achieve your desired goal! Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/G9x8V/9/